# Updating Imageview after image upload to server in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I am changing profile pic and send it server to store.But my problem is as soon as I after updating image and go back from the activity and come again to the same activity, the old image will be there replacing my new one which i have send to server.That is image saved in server in not getting in the ImageView.I am using Multipart Request to send image to server.If any one knows the solution please let me know that,I will be very gratefull.

```
private class SendGroupPicToServer extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(File... params) {

        System.out.println("inside do in background " + grp_id + "  "
                + userid);

        final File imagefile = params[0];

        RequestQueue requestQueue = MySingleton.getInstance(
                GroupProfile.this).getRequestQueue();

        Map<String, String> arguments = new HashMap<String, String>();
        arguments.put("group_id", grp_id);
        arguments.put("user_id", userid);

        MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(
                updateGroupPicUrl, arguments,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        System.out.println("Response from Abey  "
                                + response);
                        try {
                            ResponseClass rDetails = (new Gson()).fromJson(
                                    response, ResponseClass.class);
                            if (rDetails.Result.equals("Success")) {
                                profile.postInvalidate();

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(GroupProfile.this, error.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println("Upload Image response is "
                                + error.toString());
                        if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                        }
                    }
                }, imagefile, "IMAGE");
        requestQueue.add(multipartRequest);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("Image updation is  " + result);
    }

}
```

Comment: your problem is - you cant send image to server or you cant show the image on imageview ?

Comment: post some sample of code either it will be impossible for us to help you.

Comment: I can successfully post image to server,But my problem is i cant see that updation immediately after success response from server.

Comment: I am using Picasso to load image to imageview

Comment: @Lincy Why you are using Volley inside AsyncTask.  Please read more about [Android - Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html). Volley makes http requests in worker thread, no need to use it inside AsyncTask.